# How to map JSON values using Python in an iterable fashion

Tags: python, json, mapping

I have a JSON object as below that I load from a file. I want to parse the JSON object for all the CityName values.

```
{
    "CityList": [
        {
            "Continent": "USA", 
            "CityName": "Chicago"
        }, 
        {
            "Continent": "Russia", 
            "CityName": "Moscow"
        }, 
        {
            "Continent": "Asia", 
            "CityName": "Beijing"
        }, 
        {
            "Continent": "Australia", 
            "CityName": "Sydney"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using Python script to extract the CityName element from the JSON such through a FOR loop. I want to use the "name" variable  downstream for some other reasons.

```
 name=Chicago
name=Moscow
name=Beijing
name=Sydney
```

I have tried the following so far.

```
with open('city_names.json','r') as read_file:
    json_data = read_file.read()
data = json.loads(json_data)
for k,v in data.items():
    name=v['CityName']
    print(name)
```

After running the above unsuccessfully for quite some time, I keep getting this error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not 
str". I know what the issue is but unfortunately I don't know the 
fix. Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hint: your dictionary `data` has only one key, "CityList", whose value is `[{'Continent': 'USA', 'CityName': 'Chicago'}, {'Continent': 'Russia', 'CityName': 'Moscow'}, {'Continent': 'Asia', 'CityName': 'Beijing'}, {'Continent': 'Australia', 'CityName': 'Sydney'}]`.

Answer (score 1):

to get CityName, you can loop through `data['CityList']` since it is a list:

```
for v in data['CityList']:
      name=v['CityName']
      print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a list of dicts under the `CityList` key, so you should iterate over the sub-dicts of the list first and then output the value of the `CityName` key:

```
for d in data['CityList']:
    print(d['CityName'])
```